# How can I join multiple tables ( More than three ) in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

My Controller

```
        $EMS_Calibration_Records = DB::table('ems_application')
                    ->join('application', 'application.id', '=', 'ems_application.application_id')
                    ->join('ems_calibration_logs', 'ems_calibration_logs.EMS_id', '=', 'ems_application.id')
                    ->get();
        $EMS_Update_Records = DB::table('ems_application')
                    ->join('application', 'application.id', '=', 'ems_application.application_id')
                    ->join('ems_update_logs', 'ems_update_logs.EMS_id', '=', 'ems_application.id')
                    ->get();
        $EMS_Registration_Records = DB::table('ems_application')
                    ->join('application', 'application.id', '=', 'ems_application.application_id')
                    ->join('ems_insert_logs', 'ems_insert_logs.EMS_id', '=', 'ems_application.id')
                    ->get();
```

For now, I have to do many repeated joins to get the data. But I want all these joins to become one only and store the query result in one variable then pass to the front end to do the filter.

What I want to achieve is something like below:

```
        $EMS_Records = DB::table('ems_application')
                    ->join('application', 'application.id', '=', 'ems_application.application_id')
                    ->join('ems_update_logs', 'ems_update_logs.EMS_id', '=', 'ems_application.id')
                    ->join('ems_insert_logs', 'ems_insert_logs.EMS_id', '=', 'ems_application.id')
                    ->join('ems_calibration_logs', 'ems_calibration_logs.EMS_id', '=', 'ems_application.id')
                    ->get();
```

Hope can have some hints from you, thanks in advance!

Comment: The query with the 4 joins should work, but joining so many tables will probably give you a bunch of redundant results.

Comment: @IGP Yup it works but it only returns me empty result

Comment: Have you tried replacing join with `leftJoin` on one or more joins? It should give you a bunch of null columns but maybe will show a result or two.